# Why is MyFaces/Trinidad rendering my disabled inputTexts as divs?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, facelets, myfaces, trinidad

Deceptively simple question, but I'm at my wits' end here.

I have a document. It contains a form. Which contains a subform. Which contains a read-only text field. Here's the relevant part of the structure:

```
<tr:document ...>
    <tr:form ....>
        <tr:subform ...>
            <div ...><div ...>
            <tr:panelGroupLayout>
                <tr:panelFormLayout>
                    <tr:inputText id="selectedAmount"
                        label="#{...}"
                        value="#{...}"
                        disabled="true" />
                </tr:panelFormLayout>
            </tr:panelGroupLayout>
            </div></div>
        </tr:subform>
    </tr:form>
</tr:document>
```

(none of the attributes on the ... are setting style information.)

Why is it that MyFaces produces for the innermost element a div rather than input type="text"? I've seen forms with (apparently) this *exact* same structure that didn't have this problem.

The reason why this is silly and unacceptable is because the div, when empty, doesn't show as a box but as a single line (the border collapses since there is no content and no height style). Manually setting a height via css isn't acceptable either, because the font may vary from computer to computer. I really just wanted it to always render an input tag.

Any ideas? Feel free to ask for details if you want to confirm any suspicion. There's too many data for me to just dump everything in here.

Comment: I don't use Trinidad, so I don't know from top of head what HTML it generates, but have you tried `readonly="true"` instead of `disabled="true"`?

Comment: This is a workaround, but you could try something like `value="#{empty value ? '-' : value}"` to prevent getting an empty `<div>`.